# Stereoscopic rendering

Tags: 3d, xna, nvidia, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I am trying to come up with an app that renders two videostreams from webcams in a way that they are perceived as stereoscopic image on a 3D display. I have never dealt with stereoscopic 3D before, but thoretically this should be as simple as rendering the streams to two different surfaces and showing each for the appropriate eye (sorry, not fully familiar with terminology). I know that NVidia drivers can "stereoscopize" any 3D application. I also know that video games include this feature as a separate setting, so turning this on and working with it should be simple.

Nevertheless, I wasn't able to find any guides in MSDN or NVidia website on how to do this.

I would appreciate any kind of help in this area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have attached a link to a small project I found a while ago, but it was in XNA 3.1, so I've converted it to XNA 4.  It uses `RenderTargets` in order to create the effect.  You'd need to store the image from the Webcam into a `Texture2D` or a `RenderTarget` in order to amend the code.

[3D Test](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=641cd5a494d0369d&resid=641CD5A494D0369D!149&parid=641CD5A494D0369D!116)

Comment: Thanks! As I can see from the code you are supporting either Anaglyph or cross-eye method. However, I was interested in NVidia 3D Vision type of 3D, where you can see the full-color image with active glasses. Do you know how to handle that? Btw, is NVidia 3DVision the only tech that allows this?